# squaring a matrix and finding probability

Tags: matrices

Let $n ≥ 2$ be an integer, and let $O$ be the $n × n$ matrix whose entries are all equal
to $0$. Two distinct entries of the matrix are chosen uniformly at random, and those
two entries are changed from $0$ to $1$. Call the resulting matrix $A$.
Determine the probability that $A^2 = O$, as a function of $n$.

According to me, the probability should be $0$.

But my solution is not generalized so if anyone can provide a generalized solution I will be very grateful and please check my answer also.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We mark the entries of the $1$ elements as $(r_1, c_1)$ and $(r_2, c_2)$, where $r$ refers to the row number, and $c$ refers to the column number. Note, $A^2 = 0$ if any only if $r_1 \neq c_1, r_2 \neq c_2, r_1 \neq c_2, r_2 \neq c_1$. Note, there are $n$ choices for $r_1$, and $n-1$ choices for $r_2$, meaning there are $n-2$ choices for $c_1$ and $n-3$ choices for $c_2$. If we were to pick without restriction, there would be $n \cdot n$ choices for $(r_1, c_1)$ and $(n-1) \cdot (n-1)$ choices for $(r_2, c_2).$ So, the total probability is
$$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{n^2(n-1)^2} = \frac{(n-2)(n-3)}{n(n-1)}.$$

Comment: this is wrong how can the probability at $n=3$ be $0$